# xarray.plot.contour not printing contour labels

Tags: matplotlib, python-xarray

I am trying something like this:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

(lon,lat)=np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,6,1),np.arange(0,6,1))

da_data=xr.DataArray(data=np.random.randn(6,6),dims=['y','x'],
                     coords=dict(LAT=(['y','x'],lat), LON=(['y','x'],lon)) )
da_data.plot.contour(kwargs=dict(inline=True))
```

I can see the contours but no labels. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`xarray.plot` uses matplotlib as a backend, and you can replace your last line with the following, using matplotlib's [`Axis.clabel`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.clabel.html)

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
CS = da_data.plot.contour(kwargs=dict(inline=True), ax=ax)
ax.clabel(CS)
```

See the [`matplotlib.contour.ContourLabeler.clabel`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/contour_api.html#matplotlib.contour.ContourLabeler.clabel) documentation and the [countour label demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contour_label_demo.html) for more info.